# Doess Intel XDK crosswalk webRTC work in Android & iOs?

Tags: webrtc, intel-xdk

I am using Intel XDK and crosswalk android.
What I want to achieve is a webrtc app. 
Running the code in the Intel XDK emulator seems fine but when uploading it to Android phone (after having generated APK from Crosswalk), I do not see the video.

The Intel XDK logs show that the camera permission is set:

```
The App ID is "xdk.template.flipview"
The App Name is "Cam1"
Crosswalk Version: 10.39.235.15
Plugin installed: Camera (org.apache.cordova.camera)
Plugin installed: Accelerometer (org.apache.cordova.device-motion)
App name updated to [Cam1]
Updated "minSdkVersion" with "14"
Updated "targetSdkVersion" with "19"
Updated "installLocation" to "auto"
Added permission "android.permission.android.permission.CAMERA"
Added permission "android.permission.android.hardware.camera"
Added permission "android.permission.android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
Updated "versionCode" to "60001"
Updated "versionName" to "0.0.1"
Added "debuggable" to "false"
```

But I do not see this camera permission when I install the app.
Do you have any ideas? Also, will the video run when I select the iOS target?

Thanks!

Comment: I am using PeerJS and the app is packaged as CrossWalk Android. The code works fine from the emulator.

Comment: crosswalk is for Android only, not iOS

Comment: From Feb, 2017 they stopped (Crosswalk is bank-corrupted). Stop using CrossWalk and spam Cordova to bring WebRTC support, Intel is unreliable they give something and then stop it forever. making everyone handycap.